# HTMLcleaner in AsyncTask

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, htmlcleaner

I am trying to get HTML cleaner to parse the info from a website and then use Xpath to find the data I'm looking for. I have the htmlcleaner stuff in a separate AsyncTask class and the app seems to work on my phone. However, when I push the button nothing happens.  Here is my main activity class and my AsyncTask Class.

```
package ru.habrahabr.stackparser;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class stackParser extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parse);
    button.setOnClickListener(myListener);
}

private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new parseSite().execute("http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/");
    }
};

private class parseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String output = new String();
        try {
            htmlHelper hh = new htmlHelper();
        } finally {
        }

        return output;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        view.setText((CharSequence) output);
    }
}
}
```

And here's my referenced class. I'd really appreciate it if someone could look at this and tell me what's up. I tried to follow a working example and put my own Url and Xpath in but it's not working.

```
package ru.habrahabr.stackparser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;
import org.htmlcleaner.XPatherException;

public class htmlHelper {
TagNode rootNode;
String stats;

static final String XPATH_STATS = "//div[@id='blog-stats']/ul/li";


public String htmlHelper(URL htmlPage) throws IOException, XPatherException {
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    rootNode = cleaner.clean(htmlPage);

    // query XPath
    Object[] statsNode = rootNode.evaluateXPath(XPATH_STATS);
    // process data if found any node
    if (statsNode.length > 0) {
        TagNode resultNode = (TagNode) statsNode[0];
        stats = resultNode.getText().toString();
    }
    return stats;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `AsyncTask` doInBackground method as :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String output "";
        try {
            htmlHelper hh = new htmlHelper();
            output=hh.htmlHelper(arg[0]);  //<< call htmlHelper method here
        } finally {
        }

        return output;
    }
```

because you are currently only creating an instance of `htmlHelper` class not calling `htmlHelper` method from  `htmlHelper` class to get data from web url

Answer (score 1):

Look , I will not care of the data is downloaded or not , but I will assume that the data is already downloaded and besides in the variable `output` , you just need to place this code inside onPostExecute

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {

// update data into TextView.

  TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

view.setText((CharSequence) output);

                    }
                });
```

because , sometimes the data is already downloaded but needed to be assigned into Textview or whatever view by using UIthread. Hope this works for you